# What happens when I compile on machine that supports avx2 and run the binary on another machine that only supports avx?

Tags: c++, avx, avx2

I compiled my c++ program on a machine that supports avx2 (Intel E5-2643 V3). It compiles and runs just fine. I confirm the avx2 instruction is used since after I dissemble the binary, I saw avx2 instructions such as `vpbroadcastd`.

Then I run this binary on another machine that only has avx instruction set (Intel E5-2643 V2). It runs also fine. Does the binary runs on a backward compatible avx instruction instead? What is this instruction? Do you see any potential issue?

Comment: I'm not sure why this question received a down vote. I searched but cannot find the answer. Where can we find the reason for down vote, so that we can improve in the future?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not rare to have AVX2 instructions in a binary that uses CPU detection to make sure it only runs them on CPUs that support them.  (e.g. via `cpuid` and setting function pointers).

---

If the AVX2 instruction actually executed on a CPU without AVX2 support, it raises `#UD`, so the OS delivers SIGILL (illegal instruction) to your process, or the Windows equivalent.

There are a few cases where an instruction like `lzcnt` decodes as `rep bsr`, which runs as `bsr` on CPUs without BMI1.  (Giving a different answer).  But VEX-coded AVX2 instructions just fault on older CPUs.

Comment: The strange thing is that the binary runs fine on CPU that doesn't have AVX2 instruction. We didn't catch any exception and program finished with no error. For this particular instruction `VPBROADCASTD`, is it possible that  older CPU can interpret `VPBROADCASTD` as `VBROADCASTSD` which is available in AVX instruction set?

Comment: @werk: No, that's not possible, like I said VEX-coded instructions aren't a new prefix in front of an old opcode.  They use a different opcode, and different bits in the VEX prefix.  The only explanation is that the `vpbroadcastd` isn't executed at all.  (And BTW, [`vbroadcastss`](http://felixcloutier.com/x86/VBROADCAST.html) is the equivalent, to broadcast 4 bytes, a dword.)  Fun fact: even the reg-reg form of `vbroadcastss/sd` requires AVX2.  Only the broadcast-load form is AVX1.

Comment: If you're not convinced, edit the binary and replace the `vpbroadcastd` with [`ud2`](http://felixcloutier.com/x86/UD.html), `0F 0B`.  Or with `int3` (debugger breakpoint).  Or more simply, **run it under a debugger with a breakpoint set at that instruction, and notice that it was never hit**.  (In GDB, `b *0x12345` to set a breakpoint at a numeric address).  Did you compile with Intel's compiler or something, which did runtime CPU dispatching?

Comment: What you're saying is exactly what I am thinking of. I just had a double check. Looks like it's the [fftw](http://www.fftw.org/) that we're using are compiled with avx/avx2. In this [webpage](http://www.fftw.org/fftw3_doc/Installation-on-Unix.html) it says "Enable various SIMD instruction sets. You need compiler that supports the given SIMD extensions, but FFTW will try to detect at runtime whether the CPU supports these extensions. That is, you can compile with--enable-avx and the code will still run on a CPU without AVX support. ".

Comment: In our case we compile fftw as dynamic library and link with it when we compile our source code. So according to fftw, looks like we can compile on avx2 CPU and later run the program on avx CPU. So what's the trick behind this? Is there any guarantee for the computing results is also of our concern.

Comment: @werk: libraries can do runtime dispatching to different versions of a function just as easily as executables.  Video encoders like x264 and x265 do this as well.  https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/FunctionMultiVersioning
 is one way of doing this, but many major libraries will roll their own custom dispatching.

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple compilers and multiple settings you can use but the general principle is that usually a compiler is not targeting a particular processor, it's targeting an architecture, and by default it will usually have a fairly inclusive approach meaning the generated code will be compatible with as many processors as reasonable. You would normally expect an x86_64 compiler to generate code that runs without AVX2, indeed, that it should run on some of the earliest CPUs supporting the x86_64 instruction set.

If you have code that benefits greatly from extensions to the instruction set that aren't universally supported like AVX2, your aim when producing software is generally to degrade gracefully. For instance you could use runtime feature detection to see if the current processor supports AVX2 and run a separate code path. Some compilers may support automated ways of doing this or helpers to assist you in achieving this yourself.

Comment: Normally for runtime dispatching you'd use compiler features like GCC function multiversioning (https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Function-Multiversioning.html), or you'd do it manually (e.g. with function pointers) and compile some versions of your C++ source files with `-march=haswell` (AVX2+FMA+BMI1/2), autovectorized or manually with intrinsics.  Or `__attribute__((target("avx2,fma"))`.  A couple major projects (notably video codecs x264 and x265, and FFmpeg) have some hand-written assembly instead of using C++ with intrinsics, but it's not the recommended go-to way.

Comment: Thanks for the insight. x264 is one of the few major projects I've ever messed with the source code of and it's what I had in mind writing this. I may edit to point out that's not typical.